# Calling .map() on property defined as a Union Type

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an object typed as

```
interface Asset {
  id: string;
}

interface Project {
  assets: Array<string> | Array<Asset>;
}
```

Now if I run the following:

```
const project: Project = {
  assets: [
    {id: '1'}.
    {id: '2'},
    {id: '3'},
    {id: '4'}
  ],
};
project.assets.map((asset: Asset) => asset.id);
```

I get this error

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | ((callbackfn: (value: Asset, index: number, array: Asset[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has no compatible call signatures.

This error persists even if I change the callback to

```
project.assets.map((asset: Asset | string) => {console.log(asset)});
```

Why does this occur and how do I fix this?

Comment: It's because TS can't determine what's the final type of your `project.assets`. You could call it your map function like this with type assertion and it'll work: `(project.assets as Asset[]).map((asset: Asset) => asset.id)`. It also won't let you assert it's type as i.e. `number[]` because TS still checks if your assertion fits with your type definition.

Comment: @dziraf That works perfectly. Can you add this as an answer so other people looking for the same issue can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because TS can't determine what's the final type of your `project.assets` array. You could call the map function like this with type assertion and it'll work:

`(project.assets as Asset[]).map((asset: Asset) => asset.id)`

It also won't let you assert it's type as i.e. `number[]` because TS still checks if your assertion matches your type definition.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the interface of Project to:

```
interface Project {
  assets: Array<string|Asset>;
}
```

or

```
interface Project<T> {
  assets: Array<T>;
}

const project: Project<Asset> = {
  assets: [
    {id: '1'}.
    {id: '2'},
    {id: '3'},
    {id: '4'}
  ],
};
project.assets.map((asset: Asset) => asset.id);
```

Comment: That would work and remove the error but it would be incorrect typing since `Array<string|Asset>` will allow the project to be initialised as `{asset: ['1', {id: '2'}, 3]}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is possible without generics, but it works at least.

```
interface Project<T extends string | Asset> {
    assets: Array<T>;
}
const project: Project<Asset> = {
    assets: [
        {id: '1'},
        {id: '2'},
        {id: '3'},
        {id: '4'}
    ],
};
project.assets.map((asset) => {})
```